# sql server for xml clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-xml-path

I have data in the following format:

```
   user          Id         Value
   -------------------------------
   a             50000        5              
   a             50000        6   
   a             50000        7   
   b             50001        8   
   b             50001        9   
   b             50001        10
```

I would like to get a formatted XML in the following format

```
 <RootNode> 
     <User "a"> 
       <UserAttribute Id="50000" value="5"/>
       <UserAttribute Id="50000" value="6"/> 
       <UserAttribute Id="50000" value="7"/> 
     </User> 
     <User "b">
       <UserAttribute Id="50001" value="8"/> 
       <UserAttribute Id="50001" value="9"/> 
       <UserAttribute Id="50001" value="10"/> 
     </User>
 </RootNode>
```

I have tried the following select query :

```
select 
   [user] as '@user', 
   [id] as 'UserAttribute/@id',
   [value] as 'UserAttribute/@value' 
from 
   dbo.test 
for xml path('User')
```

but it doesn't give the required output. Could someone let me know as to what I am missing?

The current output:

```
<User user="a">
  <UserAttribute id="50000" value="5" />
</User>
<User user="a">
  <UserAttribute id="50000" value="6" />
</User>
<User user="a">
  <UserAttribute id="50000" value="7" />
</User>
<User user="b">
  <UserAttribute id="50001" value="8" />
</User>
<User user="b">
  <UserAttribute id="50001" value="8" />
</User>
<User user="b">
  <UserAttribute id="50001" value="8" />
</User>
```

Comment: What does “doesnt seems to work” mean? You get an error message? Post the error message. It gives the wrong results? Show us what results it gives.

Answer (score 0):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE ([user] CHAR(1),Id INT, Value INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('a',50000,5),              
('a',50000,6),   
('a',50000,7),   
('b',50001,8),   
('b',50001,9),   
('b',50001,10)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT t.[user]        AS [@User]
       ,(SELECT Id     AS [@Id]
                ,Value AS [@Value]
         FROM @TABLE 
         WHERE [user] = t.[user]
         FOR XML PATH('UserAttribute'), TYPE)
FROM @TABLE t
GROUP BY t.[user]
FOR XML PATH('User'), ROOT('RootNode')
```

**Result:**

```
<RootNode>
  <User User="a">
    <UserAttribute Id="50000" Value="5" />
    <UserAttribute Id="50000" Value="6" />
    <UserAttribute Id="50000" Value="7" />
  </User>
  <User User="b">
    <UserAttribute Id="50001" Value="8" />
    <UserAttribute Id="50001" Value="9" />
    <UserAttribute Id="50001" Value="10" />
  </User>
</RootNode>
```

*Note*

User tag have to have the [User] value as an attribute, you cannot just add a character to a tag like you have shown in your desired output. `<User "a">` this is not a valid format for XML you need [User] values as attributes as shown in my output `<User User="a">`